# Avoiding Landing Page Redirects with SSL

Tags: performance, .htaccess, url, redirect, ssl

I recently did a Google PageSpeed analysis of my website and received the following message:

> Avoid landing page redirects
>
> Your page has 2 redirects. Redirects introduce additional delays
>   before the page can be loaded.
>
> Avoid landing page redirects for the following chain of redirected
>   URLs.
>
> http://example.net/
>
> https://example.net/
>
> https://www.example.net/

Is there anything I can do about this (like modifying my htaccess file in some way), or is this an unavoidable consequence?

Here is my htaccess just in case:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine the two redirects into one by using the `OR` flag

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. Should this resolve the above PageSpeed complaint, or is it just a general optimization you're suggesting?

Comment: @JohnRoberts there's no way to avoid the landing page redirect since you want to enforce a "www" and "https://" scheme, but at least this is only 1 redirect as opposed to 2.